# How reliable are current 2 TByte consumer grade disk drives?

Tags: raid, hard-drive

Most cheap SATA disk drives are rated with "1 non-recoverable read error per 10^14 bits read".

What does this mean?

10^14 bits is just 12.5 TByte. If I have a full 2 TByte disk and I copy it to a second disk, is there in fact a chance of roughly 1/6 that one of the files is corrupted?

If this happens, will the affected block be marked and reallocated? I think so because if the read would be successful on retry, it's not a non-recoverable read error.

However I am using lots of these disk drives for a couple of years now, I haven't noticed any increase of bad blocks count, also the RAID controller logs do not show any read problems.

EDIT: The RAID controllers do a weekly patrol read of each disk, so that amounts to about 100 TByte per year. That is still less than 10^15 bits.

On the other hand there were 4 total disk failures out of 50 disks within 2 years which increases the error rate.

I don't have enough statistically significant data to make statements but in my case the actual error rate seems to be between 10^14 and 10^15 which is consistent with the specification.

Comment: You may want to read http://sysadmin1138.net/mt/blog/2008/10/an-old-theme-made-new.shtml and http://www.zdnet.com/blog/storage/why-raid-5-stops-working-in-2009/162.

Comment: "1 per 10^14" does not mean "1 every 10^14". It is a statistic (an average, like 2.1 children per family, one family has none, one has 5, but none has 2.1) There can be zero errors in 10^15 reads, and then 10 errors in a row afterwards. Or millions in a row (failed disk). Or no error in 10^16 reads and then a lot right after that in clusters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statistic given 1 read error in 10^14 is just that, a statistic data point. It doesn't mean that in any given disk you will see errors and it doesn't say that it necessarily happens from the start of the disk life to the end. It only means that the disk is not rated as high as the enterprise disks and based on my experience (developing enterprise storage systems) both the consumer and the enterprise disks never reach the full MTBF numbers either. I don't remember a big difference between them either. There was some difference but not a very big one.

When a block is being read and that fails, then the disk will put the sector to a holding list.When the sector is next written, the write will be attempted and the sector is verified, if that works nothing will be done any further. If the verification fails the sector will be reallocated.

In many cases the disks and the RAID can correct bad sectors on the fly even before they get to be a big problem. There is a background media scan of the disk and the disk scrub of the RAID array and both of these work to protect the data. Enterprise storage arrays use finer grained checks to make sure that even slightly problematic disk sectors will be treated and fixed.

There are other issues with using consumer drives in a RAID array, TLER is one of them, it essentially means that you may lose the disk for even one bad sector, since the disk stops responding until it succeeds to read the sector. TLER is actually the method to avoid the RAID calling the disk failed when it's just a small media problem. If you have TLER enabled the disk will quickly give up on the sector and let the RAID handle the failure at its level.

Answer (score 4):

You should be careful with RAID and consumer drives. Depending on your RAID controller, it will throw up if the disk takes too long to respond because of not having [TLER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_recovery_control).

What happens to an unrecoverable block is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_sector)

> When a sector is found to be bad or unstable by the firmware of a disk
>   controller, the disk controller remaps the logical sector to a
>   different physical sector. In the normal operation of a hard drive,
>   the detection and remapping of bad sectors should take place in a
>   manner transparent to the rest of the system and in advance before
>   data is lost. It should be remembered, however, that the damaging of
>   the physical body of the hard drive does not solely affect one area of
>   the data stored. Very often physical damages can interfere with parts
>   of many different files.

As to your question about the 1/6 chance that a block is corrupted, that is true for the block, however, Operating Systems / File Systems have their own ways of dealing with bad blocks, and recovery from it, so it is quite possible that the OS/FS is able to recover the bad block on it's own, without you noticing any corruption of files.

Comment: Usually there's recovery and protection. The gotcha is RAID rebuilds in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

What that means is that their quality control is set such that you may expect there to be one unrecoverable read in every 12.5TB read.
That doesn't mean there will be one, merely that that's where their quality control has been calibrated.

This has some quite serious implications when you consider RAID groups - a 5+1 RAID 5 set of 2TB drives is coming close to this number. A RAID rebuild requires a rescan of the whole RAID group, and so your odds of a rebuild failure start to become significant. Partial solutions involve smaller RAID groups or using RAID 6, but that comes with it's own consequences. (RAID-6 in particular, whilst clever, will burn you on write penalty especially on 'cheaper/slower' disks).

This is why 'server disks' are 'so expensive' - one of the key reasons is they tend to be 1 / 10^16 - this decreases the odds of compound failure massively.

But you should note - just because the expected error rate is 12.5TB, that doesn't mean you won't be unlucky. RAID is never a substitute for backups. (But I suspect you already know that.)